# Setting a process' window to front. Why isn't this working when maximized?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

I'm trying to get an app's window (let's say Firefox as an example) and bring it to the very front and focus it. It works fine when the program isn't maximized, allowing me to bring any of Firefox's windows to the front.

However when maximized, it just brings the whole group of windows to the front, regardless of whether or not it was the window I specifically chose. Here's what I'm using:

```
AXUIElementPerformAction (element, kAXRaiseAction);
ProcessSerialNumber psn = [self serialNumberOfPid: [appPid unsignedIntValue]];
SetFrontProcessWithOptions (&psn, kSetFrontProcessFrontWindowOnly);
```

Reading some other posts, I've tried this:

```
AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(element, kAXMainAttribute, kCFBooleanTrue);
AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(element, kAXFocusedAttribute, kCFBooleanTrue);
AXUIElementPerformAction (element, kAXRaiseAction);
    ProcessSerialNumber psn = [self serialNumberOfPid: [appPid unsignedIntValue]];
SetFrontProcessWithOptions (&psn, kSetFrontProcessFrontWindowOnly);
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does it only happen when the windows are maximized? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: "Maximized" isn't the usual Mac terminology. Do you mean that you pressed the green button on the window (sizing it to its so-called optimal size), or did you press the diagonal-arrows button in the right corner, putting it into fullscreen?  Fullscreen is new in Lion and still has some quirks.

Comment: I don't mean fullscreen, I do mean the green button which makes the window fill up the available space. It happens if all of the windows for that screen have "filled up the screen" (the whole screen, though with each window behind another).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `kAXFrontmostAttribute` property:

```
AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(element, kAXFrontmostAttribute, kCFBooleanTrue);
```